# Как из колбек функции передать значения в swift 3

Tags: swift

Есть переменная `var menus: Any = []` в которую, нужно записать данные от сюда

```
self.httpRequest.getJsonMenu(){ code in
        print("Menu2: \(code)")
        return code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как обычно, если она видима.

```
var menus: Any = []
...
self.httpRequest.getJsonMenu(){ code in
    print("Menu2: \(code)")
    menus = [code]
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, это не срабатывает.

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос с описанием критериев "срабатывания".

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте если code это 1 элемент

```
var menus: Any = []
...
self.httpRequest.getJsonMenu(){ code in
   print("Menu2: \(code)")
   menus.append(code)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Объявил переменную `var menus: Any = []` глобально

P.S.  Скорей всего моя вина, не правильно объяснил вопрос.. Данная функция выполняла асинхронный запрос